# how to get all keys in a redis(codis version) in python

Tags: redis

I want to get all keys in redis?
this is a codis version
so, there is no scan() or scan_iter() or keys()...
I know there is a function
SLOTSSCAN
but how to use it in python?
not redis-cli

Comment: anyone knows this quesiton？

Answer (score 0):

i made it!!!
use SLOTSSCAN
in python, just use send_command('SLOTSSCAN', slot, cursor)
then the response is what i want